# variable argument function

Tags: variables, arguments

while doing a program related to variable argument function i

got the header file stdarg.h  and have done some simple problem using it

but now when i a changing the actual argument's type it is showing some weird behaviour

here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdarg.h>

void fun(int a,...)
{
va_list k;

va_start(k,a);
int i=0;
printf("%d  ",a);
while((i=va_arg(k,int)!=0)
{
printf("  %d  ",i);
}
va_end(k);
}

int main()
{
fun(1,2,3,4,5,6);
printf("\n");
fflush();  //and without flush it is also showing some extra garbage value
fun(2,4,5);

printf("\n");
fflush();
fun('c','f','g','l');
return 0;
}
```

Comment: please show us your includes: indent every line with 4 spaces

Comment: How does this even *compile* ? `fflush` requires a stream parameter, e.g. `fflush(stdout)`. Even if you can get this to compile (do you just *ignore* compiler warnings ???) then you'll probably get some nasty behaviour at run-time.

Comment: ya it is giving the warning but it is running b/c no error

and as i have already mentioned that if ia m not including fflush then it is giving the extra garbage value for int too..



thanx..

Answer (score 0):

If you use the integer value 0 to indicate end of the argument list, you should also pass a 0 to fun.

```
fun(1,2,3,4,5,6,0);
fun(2,4,5,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, end your list with 0, because you check for !=0 to detect the end. And also:

```
while((i=va_arg(k,int))!=0)
```

instead of

```
while(i=va_arg(k,int)!=0)
```

!= has higher precedence than =

This will give you the expected output:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6

Here's the complete code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdarg.h>

    void fun(int a,...)
    {
    va_list k;

    va_start(k,a);
    int i=0;
    printf("%d  ",a);
    while((i=va_arg(k,int))!=0)
    {
    printf("  %d  ",i);
    }
    va_end(k);
    }

    int main()
    {
    fun(1,2,3,4,5,6,0);
    printf("\n");

    //fun(2,4,5,0);

    printf("\n");

    //fun('c','f','g','l','\0');

    getch();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: actually my previous code is correctly working for integers but the problem is that it is showing extra garbage values for the characters

the out put of the previous code is

1    2    3    4    5    6  
2    4    5  
99    102    103    108    213851632    10  


plz see it ..
thanx.

Comment: I obviously **did** see your code because i modified it. You can avoid the extra characters by adding a 0-value to the end of an argument-list (after all while((i=va_arg(k,int))!=0) checks for that null-terminator). If you dont believe me: just try my code :-)

Comment: got answer with small modification

just added 0 in characters argument list

... thanx to all